# How do I find the users of a datablock using the Python API?

Tags: python

Given a datablock `foo`, how do I determine which other datablocks are referencing it? `foo.users` will tell me how many references there are, but do I have to loop through every other datablock in the file to find those references? If so, can anyone recommend a reasonably generic way of doing this given the different interfaces of various datablock types?

For my specific application I'm trying to find and delete (or modify) datablocks with names matching a pattern. I'm mostly interested in node groups and images, which seem to acquire hidden users more easily than other objects, but this type of functionality seems generally useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way, internally Blender also doesn't store this data for easy access.

However some data types have convenience properties added to them to access **some** of the users.

- `Object.users_scene`
- `Object.users_group`
- `Object.children`

Are handy in many cases, but specific to object types.

Comment: This is further complicated by the fact that you can't assume the same type of user for a particular datablock (e.g. an image could be used by both a texture as well as a compositor node).