# How to re-link files which have paths that have become invalid (can't be found)?

Tags: texturing

I have a Blender project with planes with image textures on them, but the images aren't being loaded. I'm pretty sure I have the images as well, but the person who uploaded all this apparently didn't keep the original folder structure. Where can I see (or edit) the file location for the images?

*Note that I'm a new user.*

Comment: "external data" was the magic keyword phrase I didn't know. I found a lot of other posts, including this one: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3088/13484 - thx @Denis

Comment: The Info Editor tab can be dragged down revealing a console with a dump of all of the external data error messages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To re-link missing files, open file menu, then choose *External Data -> Find Missing Files*, and select the folder where the image textures are located. File names have to be the same as they are in the blend file.

The files are found based on matching names, the folder is searched recursively, so you can for example point it at the base of your project path, to perform a more extensive search.

[image]

Comment: That found some of them. The Report feature there is nice, too, though it only shows one file at a time. After applying the Find Missing Files, a brief list of a bunch of a alerts popped up, but they didn't last long.

For my edification, is there also a way to individually select the images in the object hierarchy and change the file attached to the texture?

Comment: Ah, this may have answer some of my question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3088/13484

Comment: @chrismo, you can drag down the file header to see all reports.