# Relink Blender files?

Tags: linked-data

I have all the production files of an open-source movie in a folder. I open up a Blender file, say `scene1.blend`, and save a copy, say `scene1_copy.blend`, in another folder. This `scene1_copy.blend`, works perfectly, knowing where to find all those assets, etc.

Now I want to move all the production files to a new folder. I tried just moving them, but then my `scene1_copy.blend` cannot find all the production files, which is no surprise.

How can I let `scene1_copy.blend` know where to look for those production files?

Comment: Linked files generally use relative paths, so if you keep the folder structure identical, Blender should still be able to find the files. Instead of a using *Save as*, try copying the files manually using a file explorer instead. Using *Save as* makes Blender remap the paths library files on save, changing their relative locations.

Comment: [File->External Data->Find Missing Files](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27859/935)