# background video for my camera has gone missing. help?

Tags: interface, edit-mode, video, keyframes

I have a video set as my camera background but for some reason its cutting out mid video. Does anyone have an idea how to get it back?

[image]

it plays the frame before this one

Comment: You seem to have moved the file to a different location... Move it back where it was or try to use the find missing files function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to re-link files which have paths that have become invalid (can't be found)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27859/how-to-re-link-files-which-have-paths-that-have-become-invalid-cant-be-found)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Blender rendered part of my vid and replaced my background vid with this incomplete one.