# Moving folders has confused blender paths

Tags: file-browser

I needed to tidy the files I am using in my blender project. After doing so blender doesnt know how to find the files as the path they were on has changed.

What can I do with blender to make sure it doesn't lose the paths when I tidy the files?

Comment: *"What can I do with blender to make sure it doesn't lose the paths"* it doesn't seem to be possible to prevent it. See for one way to fix https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27859/how-to-re-link-files-which-have-paths-that-have-become-invalid-cant-be-found.

Answer (score 0):

You can be Packing as .blend or .zip instead of saving your file directly.

You can also try setting up the File Path under the Preferences