# Finding the sources of files that are unable to pack

Tags: texturing, blend-files, file-format

I was trying to [pack all textures into my blend file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39257/packing-texture-files-in-a-single-blend-file).
When I do this, it says

> Unable to pack file, source path '...' not found

However, in my opinion, I have fixed all the paths and I can't find any pink objects which would indicate a missing texture. I'm using Cycles materials.

How do I find out which objects still use textures in an unaccessible path?

I have tried:

- opening the console to see whether it displays more information.
- select every object in my scene (luckily not so many) - none of them seems to have a missing texture
- Select `File > External data > Report missing files` - but it also displays the texture file names only, not the object names
- [How to find which materials use a missing texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/how-to-find-which-materials-use-a-missing-texture) - but the Addon fails with the error message

  ```
  for node in bpy.data.materials[mat].node_tree.nodes:
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nodes'
  ```

Comment: try also to see if this helps https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/how-to-find-which-materials-use-a-missing-texture

Comment: @m.ardito: thanks. I think that's the correct answer - unfortunately the AddOn seems broken