# Packed images files are missing... but they are no longer used! (I think...)

Tags: packed-data

I am working on a scene where I have replaced all of my textures and packed everything. However, blender is insisting that I am using a couple of textures that it can't find.

I have been going through each mesh and looking at the materials and nodes, but can't find where these are being used.

Is there a way to list all of the materials used in the scene so I can go through them one by one in case there is a mysterious mesh that I can't find?

I searched here but didn't find a thread that deals with this issue easily.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/how-to-find-which-materials-use-a-missing-texture and 
 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27859/how-to-re-link-files-which-have-paths-that-have-become-invalid-cant-be-found/27860#27860

Comment: Thank you @cegaton that helped! I didnt see those in my searches.