# How to use Image Maps with Stock Model

Tags: texturing, packed-data

I would like to know how to open a 3D stock model with all supplied image maps in place. I believe the model was created in Blender. I made a quick render and the image maps don't appear to be on the model. Perhaps my render settings or viewport settings are not optimized to actually show the image maps? Either way, I will ultimately need a high res render with image maps visible. thanks.

Comment: It the images that are used as maps are packed in the .blend file they should appear automatically. If the images were not packed, but are available as separate files you need to reconnect them manually (usually the find missing files function would help with that). If the files are not packed and not supplied as part of the download.... well you are out of luck...and will need to create those yourself or get the creator to supply them for you. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/how-to-find-which-materials-use-a-missing-texture