# How to find image's users

Tags: image, outliner, data-blocks

thanks for click my question.

In the past, when the oops Schematic function is present in the blender, 
we can found users of datablock very easily. (oops schematic was remove since 2.49b.)

But now, how can I do taht in outliner??

below is a picture of 31 unidentified users.

[image]

This image doesn't affect the project.

so i can press Shift + X or delete it from the Blend File view in the outliner.

but I'm curious what 31 users are using this image!!!

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You can use the outliner in *Datablock* mode to inspect your file, see here how to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67630/blender-2-78-file-size-grows-and-does-never-shrink

Comment: I've already tried it, but I tried again to open the data block mode.
But it isn't what I want.

What I want is not a way to erase the residual data.
The number of users is also not.
It is just what user is using this data.
Is there something I am missing?
http://imageshack.com/a/img923/9154/3Fttqp.png

Comment: As stated by one of the blender developers, there is [no easy way](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2767/935). I expect a script or addon could be created though.

Comment: personally, I wish oops schematic to be resurrected in add-on form.
The oops schematic increases the work time, but it allows intuitive grasp of the project.

Comment: While it will still need some work, try [this addon](https://gist.github.com/sambler/19729b3381f036832683ace3d712611c) and see how informative it is. I don't think I have all the use cases yet but the main ones are there. The panel is shown in the uv image editor properties (press N) for the active image.

Comment: It's a really cool add-on. And I am surprised that you write code so quickly.

I was able to use this script to find a background image at another custom layout.

15_2.png was that guy.

However, as you said, this script doesn't find any empty objects or  hidden images inside the node.

Comment: I have posted a question with an example of an image data block, but the real problem is that data blocks, such as textures (not images) and materials, are also often annoyed by unclear users.

Three years ago, there was a person who had trouble with the same problem.
Https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10758/find-users-of-a-material-texture-image-which-is-not-displayed-in-the-outline

Even the material and texture doesn't have a separate editor, so I need to create a new 3D object for check the details in the properties window.

Comment: Compared to the oops schematic, it seems that the current Blender data block management method is inconsistent.

To make the outliner as good as the oops schematic, the outliner should also provide a list of users in addition to the number of users in the datablocks or blend file mode to make it easier for finding users.

Comment: Even if your cool add-on works perfectly, it is difficult to find users of these materials if the material you find is named 'material.001, 002, 003, 004'. Especially for large, complex scenes.

Comment: Hey, I found this add-on for find user of material datablocks.
https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?317507-Addon-Simple-addon-to-display-material-relationships